# Can I use CDI to look for all qualifier-annotated methods in any beans?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, reflection, annotations, cdi

I'd like to implement a pattern for my business logic similar to the way WebSocket-annotated methods are handled.  Given the value of a particular parameter of an incoming message, I'd like to invoke an annotated method in a managed bean that is looked up on the fly.  For example, given the following setup:

```
@Qualifier
@Target( ElementType.METHOD )
@Retention( RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME )
public @interface Handler { }

@ApplicationScoped public class MyHandler1 {

  @Handler public void someMethod() { }

  @Handler public void otherMethod() { }

}
```

Then I'd like to write a function to pick a method based on that parameter value.  It should be as simple as given "someMethod" as a value and looking up my qualified managed beans with a method named "someMethod" and calling it.

My problem is that selecting beans with Instance<...> only works on type-level qualifiers and/or types.  To actually find the methods I would need to iterate through all the methods.  I'm a little worried about the cost of lookup and/or having to manage a cache or some sort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't use a qualifier to mark methods, any other annotation would do.

Then you can write a CDI extension observing the `ProcessAnnotatedType` event, if you do want to use CDI.

Having said that, from your problem description, I'm not really sure what exactly you're trying to do or whether CDI would be the best way to do it.

Comment: I'm going to mark this as answered as it looks like ProcessAnnotatedType might be the best way to implement it.  Then for each type I can scan its methods for annotations and not have to worry about proxies and synthetic methods and everything else.  Now to go read up on the SPI...

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://code.google.com/p/reflections/ to scan your classes. It is quite fast and can easily be cached. You can even use a reflections maven plugin to do the scan on compile time ...